# Telegram fork allowing to see messages without sending "Seen"

Tags: android, privacy

In [Telegram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram_(software)), messages seen by the other party are marked with a green double-check.
For instance, in the screenshot below the first message has been seen by the other party, but the second message has not been seen yet:

[image: Telegram green marks]

How to NOT make messages appear as "Seen" until I desire it?

Ideally, I would tap each message when I want the other party to see it as "Seen".

Messages appear briefly in the notification bar before I open the app to go read them, so I am sure it is technically feasible. The Telegram app is [on Github](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram), open source.

Note: It is not the same as the [Last seen](https://telegram.org/faq#q-can-i-hide-my-last-seen-time) information profiles.

Comment: Whilst it is open source would you not need to compile your own "fork" and therefore the same for other users? Secondly, whilst your question isn't really off-topic, I do not think a service (that primarily is hosted) would allow such a thing, this is probably more server side? (Added as a comment because this is all "maybe" and nothing factual...)

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow: The app is open source, everyone is allowed to create forks and distribute them, including as easy-to-install binaries (I am currently using [one such fork](https://github.com/slp/Telegram-FOSS), actually). "*therefore the same for other users*": [The API is documented](https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id) so forks are compatible, other users don't have to do anything special.